# What is the alternative of EXISTS in cassandra?

Tags: cql

I am trying to rewrite a SQLite query in CQL.

I know that there is no EXISTS keyword in CQL. I googled it's alternative. However, I couldn't find anything.

```
UPDATE users SET passsword = ? WHERE user_name = ? AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM 
users WHERE user_name = ? AND active_status = 1)
```

How can I write this query in CQL? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0 - should be able to achieve with this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
This query may be broken down to 2 queries and put an additional java logic to filter the subqueries.That will be 2 calls to database layer
Resultset rs = stmt.execute ("SELECT user_name FROM 
users WHERE active_status = 1");
while ( rs.next()){
  stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE users SET passsword = ? WHERE user_name = "+rs.next());
}
```